# bat file to backup folder files only if changed increment name

Tags: batch-file, backup, xcopy

I'm trying to create a bat file (xp/7) to copy all files in a local folder to a network drive folder but only if the files have changed. If they have changed I'd like to increment the file name by one or put a date (this seems like people have said it's easier).

For example, I have a folder called database which contains 4 or 5 files whos content or names may change occasionally I would like to automatically make copies of them on a network drive, either daily or every hour if they are changing.  Not all the files will change every day but if they do change I would like to increment their file name to keep the previous versions.

How would I go about doing this, is there a better way to go about this?

Thank you

Comment: You can use forfiles http://ss64.com/nt/forfiles.html in your batch script to target files that have changed within your window.  Then it's just standard commands like cp source destination and use windows variables to tie in the %date% into the name of the file.  Use scheduled tasks to run it hourly.

Comment: Xp doesn't give the option to run hourly for scheduled tasks though i could probably just do a new scheduled task every hour,  Does forfiles get any more detailed then day.

The junky program I use tends to corrupt database files (and overwrite) randomly which is why i'd like to have a copy on a network drive that is recent

Comment: It's been a while, but I thought there was a way with XP to schedule the task once a day, then go into the advanced settings and have it repeat as much as you want to accomplish that.  forfiles just allows you to grab and return files that match whatever you throw at it.  I've typically used it to delete files older than X day's, but it does look like it's only based on days.  Got ya on the corruption... You could add %date%%time% to get a more unique filename, but I am not sure that's the best way now, knowing how often you'd like to run it.

Answer (score 0):

This is untested - it should copy the changed files by adding a date and time stamp of when the bat was launched, and also copy files that don't exist.

Wmic which is used to get a robust date stamp requires XP Pro and above.

```
@echo off
cd /d "local folder"
set "remote=\\server\share"
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime  ^| find "."') do set "dt=%%a"
set "YYYY=%dt:~0,4%"
set "MM=%dt:~4,2%"
set "DD=%dt:~6,2%"
set "HH=%dt:~8,2%"
set "Min=%dt:~10,2%"
set "Sec=%dt:~12,2%"
set fullstamp=%YYYY%-%MM%-%DD%_%HH%-%Min%-%Sec%

for %%a in (*.*) do (
   if exist "%remote%\%%a" (
     for %%b in ("%remote%\%%a") do if not "%%~ta"=="%%~tb" copy "%%a" "%remote%\%%~na-%fullstamp%%%~xa"
   ) else (
     copy "%%a" "%remote%"
   )
)
```